# Orbitron and Pyephem has different output (Lat and Long)

Tags: pyephem

I tried to use the pyephem library to get the lat, long of a particular satellite. However, when I compare this to what was outputted by Orbitron, the latitude was different. Why is this different?

Output from my code:
Lat: -50.675605
Lon: -153.489527

Orbitron: 
Lat : 50.8527ｰ S
Lon: 153.4899ｰ W

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import ephem
import datetime
import functions
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from math import degrees


name_ = "SATELLITE"
tle1 = "1 41463U 98067HT  16264.56991668  .00008327  00000-0  11928-3 0  9991"
tle2 = "2 41463  51.6441 300.8543 0000382  62.9562  67.6735 15.57105765 22715"


sat = ephem.readtle(name_,tle1,tle2)

strDate = "2016-09-21 10:05:47"
date_obj = datetime.strptime(strDate,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
date_ = date_obj + timedelta(hours=-9)
sat.compute(date_)
print("longitude: %f - latitude: %f" % (degrees(sat.sublong), degrees(sat.sublat)))
```